# Full-text query doesn't work on Jackrabbit-standalone-server, but works on jackrabbit-webapp

Tags: java, lucene, jcr, jackrabbit

I am using Apace JackRabbit as the document repository in my project. I found that when I use jackrabbit-webapp as a remote repository, you can full-text query the contents of the document. But when use jackrabbit-standalone-server, the query result always is empty.

The code is exactly the same except the repository's url, like this:

```
// put a file into repository
Repository repository = new URLRemoteRepository(url); 
Session session = repository.login(...);
......
Node fileNode = rootNode.addNode(name, JcrConstants.NT_FILE);
Node resNode = fileNode.addNode(JcrConstants.JCR_CONTENT, JcrConstants.NT_RESOURCE);
String mimeType = MimeUtil.getMimeType(filename);
resNode.setProperty("jcr:mimeType", mimeType);
BinaryValue fileBinary = new BinaryValue(inputStream);
resNode.setProperty(JcrConstants.JCR_DATA, fileBinary);
session.save();

// query
String xPath = "//element(*, nt:file)[(jcr:contains(jcr:content,\"" + keyword + "\"))]";
Workspace ws = session.getWorkspace();
QueryManager qm = ws.getQueryManager();
Query query = qm.createQuery(xPath, Query.XPATH);
QueryResult result = query.execute();
NodeIterator it = result.getNodes();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Node node = it.nextNode();
    list.add(node);
}
```

The repository was created by jackrabbit automatically, I didn't do any configuration.
The url of webapp on tomcat is http://localhost:8080/jackrabbit-webapp-2.8.0/rmi.
The url of standalone server is http://localhost:8082/rmi.

I tried everything to find out the difference between webapp mode and standalone-server mode, even compared the log file of them on debug-level, but didn't figure it out. Standalone-server is also a web app with embedded jetty, why it is different on query?

I also tried using luke(a lucene index explorer) to check the generated index file. The node's property, such as jcr:createdBy, are indexed on both, and can be queried out successfully. But the document's content(full-text) is only indexed on webapp. Delete the index folder then restart server to rebuild index doesn't change anything. It is obviously that on standalone-server, lucene doesn't index the file's content at all.

I want my project can bundle jackrabbit inside one JVM, that is, I want to use embedded deploy mode finally. It failed for above issue, then I tried the standalone-server, still doesn't work. The versions are 2.8.0 and 2.14.0.

It stuck me two days, can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the same SearchIndex/indexing configuration for both?

Comment: I didn't make any configuration. All by default. The repository are automatically created by the first time boot with default configuration.

Comment: Jackrabbit should still create the config files if they don't exist. Have you checked they are identical? Have you checked the logs for errors?

Comment: Yes, I checked the repository.xml in /jackrabbit folder and the workspace.xml in /jackrabbit/workspaces/default folder, they are same on tomcat and standalone server.

Comment: And，I didn't find any error logs in jackrabbit.log at all. Everything seems fine except the full-text query doesn't work.